# [OCMock][OCMVerify]Why does OCMVerify still pass when I don’t call a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock

for example：

```
id mockDelegate = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(managerDelegate));
self.vc.delegate = mockDelegate;
OCMExpect([mockDelegate someMethod:OCMOCK_ANY]);

... Execute some methods to make vc.m respond to someMethod delegate callback...

OCMVerify(mockDelegate);
```

I implemented the above method and found that even if the class does not respond to the someMethod method, OCMVerify still judges it passed. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using strict mocks, please have a look at section 7 of the documentation:
https://ocmock.org/reference/#strict-mocks-and-expectations

It's easy to overlook but you have to use `OCMVerifyAll` for verifying expectations. `OCMVerify` is used for something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would also like to ask whether the function OCMVerifyAllWithDelay should be written before the target method to be tested is called or after it is called？

Comment: All verify methods should go after the methods that are tested.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ！